# Load class from war before ear in JBoss 5

Tags: classloader, war, jboss5.x, ear

I have an ear which contains a war.
Jars are in the ear lib directory.

I need to override a class from a jar and I wrote it in the war.

But when I deploy the ear, the classloader takes the class from the jar and not from the war.

I set this configuration in the jboss-web.xml in the war. I believe it forces the classloader to take classes from war before jar but it doesn't work.

```
<class-loading java2ClassLoadingCompliance="false">
    <loader-repository>
        com.example:archive=unique-archive-name
    <loader-repository-config>java2ParentDelegation=false</loader-repository-config>
    </loader-repository>
</class-loading>
```

How can I force the jboss classloader to take classes from war before the jar ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the jboss-web.xml configuration of the war is ignored when it is embedded in an ear (see 
http://www.openscope.net/2010/07/15/setting-up-a-jboss-instance-v5-x-class-loading/).
Have you tried to use **jboss-classloading.xml** files and to add the **top-level-classloader** attribute in the war (see http://phytodata.wordpress.com/2010/10/21/demystifying-the-jboss5-jboss-classloading-xml-file/)?